# how to stop a sprite from leaving the screen

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

I am using the accelerometer to move a sprite around the screen but I don't want to leave the screen.

I try with this

```
self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self;
        self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:self.frame];
        self.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = edgeCategory;


sprite.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = edgeCategory;
```

But the sprite still leaves the screen

I also change the scene anchor point

```
self.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);
```

Comment: I believe you have to set bit asks on both bodies.

Comment: I already suggested that.  I don't think he set the sprites categoryBitMask.

Comment: I suggest you post the code that creates your sprite.

Comment: @0x141E This is aa screenshot http://goo.gl/lzwy6K and this is the code that make the new sprite SKSpriteNode *sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor redColor] size:CGSizeMake(90, 90)];
        sprite.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake(90, 90)];
        sprite.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
        [self addChild:sprite];

Comment: the physicsBody of the sprite is not positioned correctly, if i remove self.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5); there position match

Comment: How are you moving the sprite if its dynamic property is NO? If you are moving the sprite by changing its position (i.e., sprite.position = ...), it will not react when it collides with the walls.

Comment: in touchesBegan i set the sprite .dynamic = YES; and applyImpulse:CGVectorMake(0, 30)

Comment: What is the value of edgeCategory? Make sure it's not zero.

Comment: static const uint32_t edgeCategory = 0x1 << 2;

Comment: I can make the borders to work but this part of the code have to be removed self.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5); because the PhysicsBody of the sprite is bellow the bottom border and that stops the sprite to go jump up.

Comment: You shouldn't change the anchor point of the scene. All of its children will be drawn at an offset.

Answer (score -1):

Try creating 4 rectangle SpriteNodes and making them very thin, long lines that make up your border.  Give them all the same CategoryBitMask, etc.

This way, You can set the roof and floor using self.size.width as the length and around 1 or two as the thickness.  Opposite for the Sides.

This will ignore the problem I think you are having where the scenes physicsBody rectangle is not centered to the middle of the screen.

If you did not previously do this, using your method:

Set sprite.categorybBitMask = spriteCategory;
Set self.collsionBitMask = spriteCategory;

one of the nodes MUST BE DYNAMIC! for collision to work.

Comment: nothing happen, but I notice the borders are made but not around the screen, maybe because I change anchor point of the scene, but how to set borders with this anchor point

Comment: Enable ShowPhysics as well to check where the boundaries are being created

Comment: i enable the ShowPhysics but the sprite don't contact the border. Maybe because the sprite is child of another sknode

Comment: http://goo.gl/Bm42ZQ - one more picture on first load. The sprite is in the middle because of self.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5); but the physicsBod body of the sprite is not